# Can I import "next/image" with a different name?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

In one of my component, I need both of the followings:

`import Image from 'next/image';` (which comes from NextJS)

`Image()` (which comes from TypeScript)

And those two are conflicting with each other.

Is it possible to give a different name to the `next/image`? I tried

`import Image as image from 'next/image';`

and

`import {Image as image} from 'next/image';`

But they didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways:

```js
// CommonJS style
const { default: NextImage } = require("next/image");
```

```js
// ES module style
import NextImage from "next/image";

// alternatively
import { default as NextImage } from "next/image";
```

Comment: Thanks! But how does that work? Are NextImage and Image the same?

Comment: @TerryWindwalker What do you mean by "the same?" `NextImage` will just be an alias for Next.js's [`<Image />` component](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image).

Comment: OK got it, thanks.